# Wordpress author details plugin/widget

Tags: plugins, widgets

Does anyone know any wordpress plugin to display the author's profile & image **similar** to the image attached
[image: Authors Details]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here are a few:

- [Author Bio Widget](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/author-bio-widget/)
- [Just Another Author Information Widget](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/just-another-author-widget/)
- [User Bio Widget](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/user-bio-widget/)